# Apache Solr URLDecoder: Invalid digit (r) in escape (%) pattern error

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to get a solr plugin (somantic knowledge graph plugin) to successfully work, but I keep getting the error below. I have spent hours trying looking on github, stackoverflow, etc. for help but none of the solutions online are helping my situation. More specifically, I do not know what the meaning of the message "URLDecoder: Invalid digit (r) in escape (%) pattern" is and how to address it.

This link (https://www.slideshare.net/treygrainger/the-apache-solr-semantic-knowledge-graph) takes you to the step-by-step instructions the plugin creator has given, to give you some information of where I am at right now. I am very new to solr, so any advice is appreciated!

```
    curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream' --data-binary @semantic-knowledge-graph-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar http://localhost:8983/solr/.system/blob/skg.jar
{
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"URLDecoder: Invalid digit (r) in escape (%) pattern",
    "code":400}}
```

Update: I tried a suggestion of replacing ' with " and this is what happened. Not sure what the error means.

```
C:\Users\lalong\Downloads\solr-8.2.0\bin\semantic-knowledge-graph\knowledge-graph>curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary @semantic-knowledge-graph-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar http://localhost:8983/solr/.system/blob/skg.jar
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "rf":1,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":737}}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? `'` will not behave the same way when given as an argument. Replace it with `"`. While it shouldn't change anything, also add a space after `:` in the content-type header. You can also add `--trace-ascii` to the cURL command to get the complete request/response printed as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, I am on windows (worry for not specifying) I tried replacing ' with " and it gave me a new error which I am looking into:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: semantic-knowledge-graph-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "rf":1,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":221}}
```

Should I add the --trace-ascii right after the curl command? I have been adding it to various places in my script and it hasn't produced the request/response message.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command you're now using.

Comment: Just edited my original post!